# Class function calling another class function c++

Tags: c++

I have 2 classes - store and owner that has the same Print() function. owner::Print() will print its data members as well as the stores the owner owns.

```
class store
{
    store(std::string& name)
    {
        name_ = name; //name_ is a private data member
    }

    std::string getName()
    {
        return name_;
    }
    void Print()
    {
        std::cout<<"Store: "<<getName()<<std::endl;
    }
};

class owner
{
    std::string name_;
    std::vector<store> stores;

    public:
    owner(std::string& name)
    {
        name_ = name;
    }

    std::string getName()
    {
        return name_;
    }

    void Print()
    {
        std::cout<<owner.getName()<<"owns: "<<std::endl;
        // I want to call the store::Print()
    }
};

void main()
{
    owner o;
    o.Print();
}
```

this is *not the real code. Just want help.*

Comment: In order to call a`store::Print` you must have a `store` object accessible at the point where you want to call the function. If you have one it's easy, if you don't it's impossible. Do you have a store object? It hard to tell when you don't post real code.

Comment: there is in the main function.

Comment: Right, so you say that you want to print `the stores the owner owns`, so that means you got to change your `owner` class so that it has as data members all the stores that owner owns. Then you can call `store::Print` for those stores..

Comment: then make `owner::Print()` accept the object in main and run the function. like `void owner::Print(const store & obj){/*the old body*/ obj.Print();}`

Comment: ***there is in the main function*** That does not really help. It needs to be available in `owner::Print()`

Comment: No that `owner` contains a vector of `stores` to print them inside `store` you can  loop: `for (auto& myStore : stores) { myStore->Print();}` I would have liked to use const auto& but store::Print() would have to be declared as const.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to make an object of the `store` class in the main method and change the `owner::print()` method to accept an instance of store.

```
void store::Print() { 
std::cout<<"Details of store"<<data_members_of_store; 
} 


void owner::Print(store &s) { 
    std::cout<<data_members_of_owner;
    s.Print();
}
```

This parameter would be the store object, whose detail you want to be printed by the `void owner::Print()`.

---

Another possible and probably better solution would be to use  inheritance as follows -

```
class owner
{
    owner(std::string& name)
    {
        name_ = name; //name_ is private data member
    }

    std::string getName()
    {
        return name_;
    }

    void Print()
    {
        std::cout<<owner.getName()<<"owns: "<<std::endl;
        // I want to call the store::Print()
    }
};

class store : public owner
{
    store(std::string& name,std::string&owner_name)
    {
        owner(owner_name);
        name_ = name; //name_ is a private data member
    }

    std::string getName()
    {
        return name_;
    }
    void Print()
    { 
        owner::print();
        std::cout<<"Store: "<<getName()<<std::endl;
    }
};
```

You could just make the object of `store` and call it's print method which would call the `owner::print()` as well. You could use this inheritance in the reverse way as well if you want to make owner as the child class of the store.

Comment: from the description, I think the function can't be static because it'll print data members.

Comment: yep its not static

Comment: @jun then use a thing like what I wrote as a comment on your question.

Comment: well it doesnt take any parameters

Comment: @jun then how does `owner::print()` decide which store to print? Does every store has same data?

Comment: @jun see if the updated answer helps. Remember that you need to give the print method a reference of other object by which it will know the object and its details. Otherwise, as I said, how will the print method know which object its going to print (and what its data member details are). I hope you get the point I am trying to convey...

Comment: i think i forgot to mention that in the owner class there is a vector<store>.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions thus far go along the lines of passing a store object into the owner Print function. Another alternative is the owner literally owns a store. Modifying your original example it would look something like this:

```
class owner
{
public:
    owner(const std::string& name, const store& s)
     : name_(name
     , store_(s)
    {
    }

    void Print()
    {
        std::cout<<name_<<"owns: "<<std::endl;
        store_.Print();
    }
private:
    std::string name_;
    store store_;
};
```

Whether or not an owner owns a store of course completely depends on the broader context, so that's up to you really.